# What is the meaning of //N in mathematica?

Tags: programming

As the title says, What is the meaning of //N?

i can't remember it.I tried looking in documentaion center, but it came up with nothing.

Help appreciated.

Comment: See [Postfix](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Postfix.html) and [N](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/N.html).

Comment: @kale `Postfix` refers to a textual form. What the OP is looking for is in this [tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/SpecialWaysToInputExpressions.html).

Comment: This is covered very well by this [answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25616/52) which has plenty of links to the documentation.

Comment: This should be closed, but why downvote?

Comment: @rcollyer Agreed, but regardless is a good intro to `Postfix` notation.

Comment: @kale I have mixed feelings on that. Yes, it introduces the terminology, but I'm not sure if new users will be able to use the knowledge.

Comment: @belisarius This community used to be more forgiving of such simple questions.  Reference the [linked duplicate](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17333/question-on-operator-n) with its +3 as opposed to -3 as an example.  I don't know if this change is for the better or the worse, but I noted it in an update [here](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/274/handling-blatant-rtfm-cases-harmful-to-the-community/277#277).  I agree that the down-votes are not needed.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard in the link provided, there is nothing abt //N i asked in the question.

Comment: @Ramanujan Both parts of `// N` are covered in the answers to [(17333)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17333/121).  What do you mean?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Interesting update. I believe I missed the original question/answers. Thanks!

Comment: @Mr.Wizard sorry sorry, and thank u.